# Install Glassfish 4.1.2 on Eclipse Neon 3. Cannot communicate with remote Glassfish server ( versionsNotMatching )

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am a beginner and get trouble. I have setup a fresh Eclipse neon 3 (4.6.3) (Java EE), then checked for updates, then install glassfish plugging 4.1.2. And I setup Java_ee_sdk-7u3.zip (jre1.8.0_144) and Java 8 update 144. I think the remote glassfish server is in good state because I can access it via The Web Administration Console (port 4848).

However, when I create server from Eclipse and test for connection, I get message "Cannot communicate with *myServer-adress*:4848 remote server." and I see the note "glassfish 4 [stopped,${versionsNotMatching}] in Eclipse server box.
Why so? I need your help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to connect to a remote server, or do you want to have your glassfish running on your local machine?

Comment: Dear Jakob, glassfish run well on my local machine. I want to connect to the remote server. I don't understand what the note "versionsNotMatching" means? Is there any conflict between plug-ins? Thank you.